# Cannot find module node-sass while running Ionic 4

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I have a big problem with node-sass. I have installed Ionic 4 and did my 'ionic serve' but the compile process failed.
I got the following issue:

"Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'"
I tried a lot, but it is not possible for me to install the node-sass folder under my node_module. I found a notice with a node-sass bug [here]. But nothing works for me. I tried to uninstall node-sass, but this failed too.

I had the same bug with my every Ionic Project Start. I had this at Ionic V3 too. But know its not possible to get this bug fixed.

Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing *Cannot find module 'node-sass'"* problem. i will use `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to install node-sass forcefully to my project. And also what i found it node-sass required python to build their library. i installed Python in my `C:/` location to fix rebuild fail problem.